# Django REST Framework set related field by another field than PK (without NestedSerializer)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pair_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='pair.name', read_only=False)
    deposit_address = NestedReadOnlyAddressSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    withdraw_address = NestedAddressSerializer(many=False, read_only=False, partial=True)
```

`pair.name` is a unique field.

Is it possible to allow the PK assignment (`order.pair`) using the pair name.

`[POST]` `{'withdraw_address': 'x', deposit: 'address': 'y', 'pair_name': 'ETHBTC'}`

Instead of:

`[POST]` `{'withdraw_address': 'x', deposit: 'address': 'y', 'pair': 1}`

Tried looking thought the docs and did not find a solution.
Googling for an hour did not help as well.

Currently `lookup_field` can only be set on `ViewSet` and not on `Serializer`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I don't think you want a write-only field if you want to be able to accept data for it.

For a good pattern to follow, look at Django REST Framework's documentation on writable nested serializers. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

You will basically overwrite your serializer's `create()` and `update()` methods to handle setting the pair value appropriately.

Comment: I read those docs, but it seems that I will need to do either one of 2 things:
1. NestedSerializer (prefer flat over nested where I only need one field)
2. Declare the field as ReadOnly but then look it up from the request body in `perform_create` (hack)
Any clean way to go about it?

Comment: I see what you're saying. I don't think the nested relation is necessary - only overwriting create and update the way the documentation demonstrates in the writable nested field example.

However, I think using SlugRelatedField may be closer to what you're envisioning. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield